# output of awk if statement is wrong

Tags: awk

I have a file with thousand's of rows and several columns like the next one:

```
38.13,38.05,2003-04-13,2.6,12,T22:47:52,Md
```

and I want to change the value of column 4 according to the value of column 7 with a mathematical operation.

Awk code to perform this change is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {if ($7 =="Md") $4 == 1.0677*$4-0.2559; print}' input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

the output I get is:

```
38.13,38.05,2003-04-13,2.6,12,T22:47:52,Md
```

the value of 4th column should be `2.5` instead of `2.6`

I can't figure out why mathematical operation is not done. I'm getting crazy with this error.

******************* Update *******************

First of all thank you so much for being so responsive.

I follow your tips to correct awk and I get something awkward:
Data input is the same line before, code is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {if ($7 == "Md") $4 = sprintf ("%.1f", 1.0677*$4-0.2559); print}'  input_file.dat
```

and output is:

```
38.13,38.05,2003-04-13,1,88,12,T22:47:52,Md
                       ^^^
```

it adds a new column and desired updated `$4` is wrong.

I'm using macOS Ventura and `awk version 20200816`.

I can provide the file if one you want to test it.

Comment: if a line has `$7 != "Md"` ... do you want to print that line or discard/ignore it? your current code implies you only want to print lines where `$7 == "Md"`

Comment: setting aside the potential locale issue (comma separator instead of decimal), the input + the suggested `awk` code cannot generate `1,88` (or `1.88`); and even if we were to accept that `1,88` is 'correct', the `sprintf` format should generate an output with only one digit to the rigt of the separator, ie, `1,9` (or `1.9`); something's not 'right' but I can't tell at this point if it's the actual/real data file or the version of `awk`; per other Q&A's re: macOS and `awk` ... I'd want to look at getting `GNU awk` installed (via homebrew?) and see if that gets you closer to the desired result

Comment: if the input `2.6` is replaced with a `2` then the code *will* generate `1.88` (ignoring the `sprintf` format issue for a moment); this is going to tie back to the locale issue (again) whereby `awk` (under your locale) treats `2.6` as a string which is then converted to the number `2` (ie, the `.6` is dropped/ignored); in my environment `1.0677*"2.6"-0.2559` the `"2.6"` is treated as the number `2.6` and generates `2.52`, while `1.0677*"2,6"=0.2559` treats the `"2,6"` as a string and converts to the number `2` to generate `1.88`

Comment: at this point your locale appears to be an explanation for the wrong value (`1.88` instead of `2.52`) plus the different separator (`1,88` instead of `1.88`); a web search on `awk locale decimal comma` should bring up plenty of research material; I'm guessing your version of `awk` has issues with the proposed `sprintf()` function call and/or the suggested format `"%.1f"` in which case you'll need to research your version of `awk` for workarounds or consider getting `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`) installed in your environment (eg, via `homebrew`?)

Comment: as Ed's already commented, if you continue to have issues with generating the 'correct' result then consider asking a new question since both the locale issue and the `awk` version issue are unrelated to the original question

Answer (score 4):

The primary issue is that `==` is used for comparisons.

For an assignment you want to use a single `=`, eg:

```
$4 = 1.0677*$4-0.2559
```

The next issue is that `awk` (at least in my env) will assign the value `2.52012` to `$4`.  If you wish to limit `$4` to just a single digit (after the decimal) you could try using `sprintf()` to enforce a specific format, eg:

```
$4 = sprintf("%.1f", 1.0677*$4-0.2559)
```

One last issue, OP has defined the input field separator (`FS`) as `,` but forgot to define the output field separator (`OFS`) as `,`.  Without an explicit `OFS` `awk` will use a space to separate the output columns.  To use a comma for both `FS` *and* `OFS` try `BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}`.

**NOTES:**

- the reason OP's current code generates the output with comma separators is because it never actually changes any part of the input
- net result is the `print` passes the input 'as is' to stdout
- once a field is changed (in this case `$4`, but even something as simple as `$1=$1` would suffice) then the `OFS` is applied to the output

Pulling all of this into OP's current code:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {if ($7 =="Md") $4 = sprintf("%.1f", 1.0677*$4-0.2559); print}' input_file.csv
38.13,38.05,2003-04-13,2.5,12,T22:47:52,Md
                       ^^^
```

Comment: `$1 = $1`'s issue, when placed outside of the action block, can result in edge cases like this :::::::::::::::: `echo ',f2,f3,f4' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } $1 = $1'` ::::::::::  where nothing gets printed at all, because there are leading edge sep(s), so `$1 = $1` was assigning the null string into itself, which evaluates to false, and skipping the default print action block. `NF = NF` remedies that, but still skips `""` lines. something like `!NF || NF = NF` or even `NF += !NF` should print all

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
38.13,38.05,2003-04-13,2.6,12,T22:47:52,Md
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$7=="Md"{$4*=1.0677;$4-=0.2559}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
38.13,38.05,2003-04-13,2.52012,12,T22:47:52,Md
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that `,` is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`), I use pattern-action pair rather than `if` to apply action to lines where 7th column is `Md`, I change `$4` to its' value multiplied by `1.0677`, then to its' value decreased by `$4`. For all lines I do `print`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*